# TwitterKit doesn't support iOS 8.x and lower

Tags: swift, xcode, twitter, cocoapods, twitterkit

I am using the following cocoa pod for twitter.

```
target 'test' do
  platform :ios, '12.0'
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for test

  pod 'GoogleSignIn'
  pod 'TwitterKit'

  post_install do |installer|
    installer.aggregate_targets.each do |aggregate_target|
      aggregate_target.xcconfigs.each do |config_name, config_file|
        config_file.other_linker_flags[:frameworks].delete("TwitterCore")

        xcconfig_path = aggregate_target.xcconfig_path(config_name)
        config_file.save_as(xcconfig_path)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Getting the following error every time, when my deployment target is 12.0

```
"TwitterKit doesn't support iOS 8.x and lower. Please, change your minimum deployment target to iOS 9.0"
`#error "TwitterKit doesn't support iOS 8.x and lower. Please, change your minimum deployment target to iOS 9.0"
```

[image]

The most irritating part is I am getting this error when I am trying to use `po` in the console and getting 
`error: use of unresolved identifier 'count'`
along with twitter error.

Comment: Don't post images of text, post text instead.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson updated with text.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `iOS Deployment Target` for `TwitterKit` target too to `iOS 12.0` to fix this issue. It's a common mistake.

Add these lines to your Cocoapod file too.

```
platform :ios, '12.0'
use_frameworks!
```

Comment: I have updated the image, deployment target was set for twitter kit and core both 12.0

Comment: Could you post an image for cocoapod file.

Comment: Add the platform version as I've mentioned.

Comment: updated but still getting the same error. Even the pod install/update change the deployment target for twitter to 9.0

Comment: Added those lines and installed the cocoapod again?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215409/discussion-between-tapas-pal-and-frankenstein).